# Birt report viewer not working in IE9

Tags: birt

I am using birt report viewer to display report,
It works fine in IE8 but viewer not working in IE 9.
Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>

<birt:viewer

id="birtViewer" 
reportDesign='<%=request.getParameter("name")%>'
height="650"
width="900"
showParameterPage="false"
svg="true" >

</birt:viewer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to webcontent/birt/pages/layout/FramesetFragment.jsp

Add this line

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

as

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
<LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="birt/styles/style.css" TYPE="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Open IE9. 
From the top menu bar, click Tools--> Compatibility View settings --> check the box ‘Display all websites in Compatibility View’.
Click on the 'Close' button.

This should get the BIRT viewer working and the report will be displayed.